# How to run custom openedx project in localhost

Tags: python, django, devstack, openedx, edx

I have the edx-platform, ecommerce, ecommerce-themes, credentials and edx-theme directories. I have installed successfully tutor and devstack but I didn't find the way to replace these custom directories. So, what is the correct way to replace them ?

After devstack runned successfully, I tried replacing the default directories with the custom ones but when I runned `make dev.provision` I get this output

```
+ docker-compose exec -T lms bash -e -c 'source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env && cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform && NO_PYTHON_UNINSTALL=1 paver install_prereqs'
/edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env: line 13: manpath: command not found
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_prereqs
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_node_prereqs
npm install error detected. Retrying...


Captured Task Output:
---------------------

---> pavelib.prereqs.install_prereqs
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_node_prereqs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paver/tasks.py", line 201, in _run_task
    return do_task()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paver/tasks.py", line 198, in do_task
    return func(**kw)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/pavelib/utils/timer.py", line 40, in timed
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/pavelib/prereqs.py", line 332, in install_prereqs
    install_node_prereqs()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paver/tasks.py", line 333, in __call__
    retval = environment._run_task(self.name, self.needs, self.func)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paver/tasks.py", line 219, in _run_task
    return do_task()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paver/tasks.py", line 198, in do_task
    return func(**kw)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/pavelib/utils/timer.py", line 40, in timed
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/pavelib/prereqs.py", line 184, in install_node_prereqs
    prereq_cache("Node prereqs", ["package.json"], node_prereqs_installation)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/pavelib/prereqs.py", line 111, in prereq_cache
    install_func()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/pavelib/prereqs.py", line 154, in node_prereqs_installation
    raise Exception("npm install failed: See {}".format(npm_log_file_path))
Exception: npm install failed: See /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/test_root/log/npm-install.log

make[1]: *** [Makefile:217: impl-dev.provision] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pablo/Documents/prueba/devstack'
Would you like to assist devstack development by sending anonymous usage metrics to edX? Run `make metrics-opt-in` to learn more!
make: *** [Makefile:221: dev.provision] Error 2
```

**EDIT**

The directories that I have after run `make dev.provision` and `make dev.up` with the default project of devstack, are the following ones:

[Directories of default project devstack openedx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx4ZS.png)

The thing that I tried was replace the default directories with the custom directories (open-edx-platform, ecommerce, ..., etc).

Comment: Regarding devstack, please check your LMS container that your local folder is shared with the container. check what's in this folder. "/edx/app/edxapp/"

Comment: Hi @IsankaWijerathne, thank you for you comment. I make a edit to the question and add a picture of the directories that I have. I don't have so much experience with openedx or devstack, so maybe I don't know which is the correct way to run a custon openedx project when you only have these directories : edx-platform, ecommerce, ecommerce-themes, credentials and edx-theme.

Comment: what error(s) is in the /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/test_root/log/npm-install.log?

Comment: @gregory I don't have the directory /edx/app, I only have the folders that are in the picture in the edit of the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your log, you'll see the following error:

```
/edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env: line 13: manpath: command not found
```

This suggests (guessing here!) you're missing `man`. So try installing it, e.g.:

```
apt install man
```

Others have reported similar kinds of errors when using nvm, e.g. see [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/343)

Comment: Hi @gregogy I execute the command `apt install man` but the output says that it is already install, here is the output:  `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'man-db' instead of 'man'
man-db is already the newest version (2.10.2-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the npm install is failing.

I don't know if you already have node & npm installed but you could try installing it, and see what the result is afterwards.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs npm
```

If you posted the npm log file, it would help a lot. You should be able to find it, per the source code, in the directory specified by the environment variable **GEN_LOG_DIR**:

```
{Env.GEN_LOG_DIR}/npm-install.log'
```